# Finding pixel coordinates from morphological components

Tags: image-processing

I used morphological components to find the connected components in a binary image, is there a way to find the pixel postions for these integers?

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation of [`ComponentMeasurements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html), components' masks can be returned as sparse arrays.

```
testImage = Uncompress@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=t8bUL5HH", "Text"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
imgPositions = #["NonzeroPositions"] & /@ ComponentMeasurements[testImage, "Mask"][[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> {{{2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}},
> {{6, 2}},
> {{6, 4}, {6, 5}, {6, 6}}}
> ```

To convert `imgPositions` from the image's coordinate system to the more intuitive coordinates used by `Graphics`, etc., you can use:

```
y = ImageDimensions[testImage][[2]];
coordinates = Map[{-1, y} + Reverse[#]*{1, -1} &, imgPositions, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{3, 5}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}, {3, 4}, {5, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}},
> {{1, 1}},
> {{3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}}
> ```

```
Show[{Show[testImage, ImageSize -> 50], Graphics[{Red, Point /@ (coordinates + .5)}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm a bit of a newbie to mathematica, so its much appriciated when people help out.

Comment: Except that those aren't coordinates, they're array indices. Indices start at the top-left corner, which is 1/1, and the first index is the row (y-direction). Coordinates start at the bottom-left corner, which is 0/0, and the first coordinate is the x-direction. If you need coordinates, and you don't want to do the error-prone conversion yourself, the easiest way is probably `PixelValuePositions[Image[#], 1]&` - might be slower, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I got bitten by the different coordinate system too many times...